# Reducing complex vars (dicts of lists) in Ansible to simple lists

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nested-loops, ansible-2.x, ansible-filter

I have searched, scanned, and tried multiple solutions and found none yet that fit.  This seems like a simple operation.  Given Ansible vars of (for example) usernames and privileges, I want to derive filenames (for templates) to apply to each combination.
Oversimplified example:

```yaml
- task: user printing access
  vars:
    useraccess:
      superdude:
        - lpr
        - lpc
        - lpadmin
      nonprivuser:
        - lpr
  loop: # I'm at a loss
  debug:
    msg: "{{ some jinja2 expression using item transform }}""
```

The result I want from `loop` and whatever transforms/filters should be as though I had specified:

```yaml
- task: user printing access
  vars:
    useraccess:
      - superdude/lpr
      - superdude/lpc
      - superdude/lpadmin
      - nonprivuser/lpr
  loop: "{{ useraccess }}"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
```

I'v experimented with `map`, `product`, `dictitem`, and a few others with no success at yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you use `dict2items` on a dictionary, you have a `key` and a `value` attributes. Since your `value` is a list, you can now use the [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_filter.html) filter over it.

Given the task:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    folders: "{{ folders | default([]) + [item.0.key ~ '/' ~ item.1] }}"
  loop: "{{ useraccess | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0.key }}/{{ item.1 }}"
  vars:
    useraccess:
      superdude:
        - lpr
        - lpc
        - lpadmin
      nonprivuser:
        - lpr
```

This would give you the list:

```yaml
folders:
  - superdude/lpr
  - superdude/lpc
  - superdude/lpadmin
  - nonprivuser/lpr
```

---

And if you need a list right away, you can build upon it, as, after using the `subelements` filters, you can now map, from one side the users (the key of the dictionary — `.0.key`) and from the other, the sub-folders (each elements of given by the `subelements` filter — `.1`), `zip` those two lists together, and finally `map` a `join` in order to flatten the list of lists:

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: |-
      _subelements_list | map(attribute='0.key')
        | zip(_subelements_list | map(attribute='1'))
        | map('join', '/')
  vars:
    _subelements_list: "{{ useraccess | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
    useraccess:
      superdude:
        - lpr
        - lpc
        - lpadmin
      nonprivuser:
        - lpr
```

Ansible would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    _subelements_list | map(attribute='0.key')
      | zip(_subelements_list | map(attribute='1'))
      | map('join', '/')
  : - superdude/lpr
    - superdude/lpc
    - superdude/lpadmin
    - nonprivuser/lpr
```

Comment: Aha.  So this is a two-task solution?  I assume because either a) 'forward-referencing' expressions within a single `vars` structure isn't supported, b) looping over the resulting derivation wouldn't work, or c) doing all this in a single task would defeat the "KISS" principle with extreme prejudice?

I guess I'm having to overcome my mental confusion about filter inputs from 'pipes' and positional/named parameters; that's probably enhancing my difficulty in figuring these things out.  Each answer and example assists with that.  Thanks!

Comment: @RoUS this all depends on what you want to do with it. In your example, you are using a loop to debug, so, if you are going to loop in a task either way, you can definitely use the loop in that task too. (e.g. you want to use the `file` module to ensure the folder exists).

Comment: @RoUS: list construction edited in.